# Identifying a zener diode

Tags: identification

This board is from a Ford 2004 F-350 instrument cluster (speedometer, tachometer, fuel gauge etc..)  Ford has epoxied the chips down along with the solder.  I tried removing one of them and well not only damaged the traces but the part itself.

I need help identifying the component so I can get a similar part ordered.

One hoping to identify the part and would love to know if someone knows any place that has a schematic for this so I don't have to re-engineer the board with these things epoxied down.

Looking at a N19 (label) in the picture below - from what I can tell it is a Zener Diode don't know the manufacture.  I am unable to see any markings on the side - and the one I pulled it is too small to pull epoxy in hopes to have writing on the underside.

[image: SMD in Question - I believe zener diode (epoxied down)]

Comment: I've never seen a small SMD device having markings on the underside, so this is what we get to work with.

Comment: Get out a DMM and measure the diode voltage, otherwise it will be really difficult to find out what this is.

Comment: According to the green silkscreen marks adjacent to the diode is the reference designation Z3. There is also a zener diode symbol right next to that so the OP is correct that this is a zener diode.

Comment: @MichaelKaras but what voltage is that zener diode?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not sure if I can get voltage reading while it is the truck based on where it is placed so testing inside the device will be difficult.  I don't see any amplification circuit on the board itself so my first guess would be 12v or lower but that is very difficult to know for sure.  I will see if I can find some solder points I can tie into so measure a voltage while in the circuit.  Am hoping for help as the one I removed is 100% bad at this point due to the epoxy. (I didn't think so either @Marcus but never know as I don't know the manufacture)

Comment: I don't have it setup for a bench test - however I am going to see if I can get something wired in (possibly tonight) to measure it while it is hooked up.  Possibly then I can get the base voltage and then try to figure out the trigger voltage that would make sense for that package.